# How to you reference a required script that is bundled?

Tags: requirejs, breeze, durandal, asp.net-spa

I'm working with the Hot Towel SPA template and I'm trying to add in some data that I want to get from breeze. I have the breeze nuget package installed and the breeze script files are in the scripts folder of the site.

I can reference it by using the actual file name like the following:

```
define(['durandal/app', '../scripts/breeze.min.js'], function (app, breeze) {
...
});
```

However, this will break when my site is running in release mode and the script is actually bundled. Plus, it is really ugly and feels like a hack to put the full name in there.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Durandal loads external libraries via normal script calls not via requirejs. Same is true for HotTowel.

e.g. https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/index.html#L31

or if your platform supports it via bundling

https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal/blob/master/SPAJumpStart/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs#L18

Simply load breeze before requiring main.js and you should be good to go.

Comment: But how do I reference it?

Comment: `breeze` should be exposed as global if you pre-loaded it, so simply reference it in your code, same as `$` or `ko` in Durandal's samples/source.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was I was trying to pass in the breeze as a variable when I could just reference it using breeze. I was making it more difficult than it needed to be. :)